# Using .each method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Why is the following returning an error?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each( { |num| puts num } )
```

Why is this not equivalent to:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each { |num| puts num }
```

What am I missing here about the 'everything is a method' hence should follow the same pattern and parantheses can be omitted if there is no ambiguity methodology?

Comment: The different argument types are covered in [Calling Methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html)

Comment: I cannot parse your last paragraph. And, what is 'everything is a method'? I have never heard of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that's syntactically invalid. That isn't a supported syntax for passing a block to a method.

Ruby's syntax allows for one special block argument to each method, apart from the regular arguments. The argument is defined differently (via the `{ |args| ... }` syntax) and (optionally) accepted differently through a final `&variable` parameter:

```
def my_method(arg1, arg2, &block)
  block.call("ok1")
  # or, a special syntax for calling the &block:
  yield "ok!"
end

my_method(value_for_arg_1, value_for_arg_2) do |arg|
  # when invoked by my_method, arg will be "ok!"
end
```

You can pass the block as part of the argument list, but again, a specific syntax is required:

```
my_block = Proc.new { puts "I'm a proc" }

my_method(value1, value2, &my_block)
```

The above `&my_block` is required only if you intend to pass the proc through as the `&block` parameter; you can pass an arbitrary number of procs through without using `&`, but they aren't callable via `yield`.

Comment: *That isn't a supported syntax for passing a block to a method.* - Not a concrete statement. The way OP write the code, MRI never will treat/know that it is a block. It will treat it as a *Hash*. But `Hash` syntax is not as per the Ruby Hash syntax, so the error popped up. **It is not due to the valid block** IMHO

Comment: @ArupRakshit That is absolutely a concrete statement. The syntax is not supported. Full stop. I don't have to elucidate *why* that's invalid syntax; you might as well ask why I can't write `if x` in C++ instead of `if (x)`: It's *not valid syntax*.

Comment: Yes.. It is not *to the point*.. What I just said, is the actual point.

Comment: I don't know other languages, I wouldn't consider them also. I am in Ruby. My opinions are only based on Ruby. You said it is not a **valid syntax for passing blocks**.It should be by observation, **It is not a valid syntax of passing Hash**. Error comes due to wrong syntax of *Hash*, not *blocks*.

Comment: He's not trying to pass a hash. He's trying to pass a block. That it is interpreted as a hash is incidental and unrelated. It isn't a valid syntax for defining a block.

Comment: Technically, he isn't. He isn't *technically* doing anything but producing a syntax error. His *intent* was to define a block, and he's chosen an invalid syntax for doing so.

Comment: No issue.... Please carry on.. The question was all about the difference between 2 styles. *Objection* is why *one parsed, but the other is not*..

Comment: Great! that clarifies my doubt - i am passing a block to a method which is not an object. Proc-ifying it settles the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because **a block is not an object**. An argument must be an object. You cannot replace an argument with a block or vice versa. You cannot enclose a block within parentheses and treat it like an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you pass block into method (like in this case), you put it outside parantheses, even if you use them for other arguments.